# base64_encode(php) vs Convert.ToBase64String(c#)

Tags: php, c#, base64

В php один результат. В c# другой.

```
$massiv = [10,202,3];
$massiv = array_map("chr",$massiv);
$rezult= implode('',$massiv);
$temp = base64_encode($rezult);
echo $temp
Результат --> CsoD


 List<int> lst = new List<int>(){10,202,3};
        var rez = string.Join("",lst.Select(x => Convert.ToChar(x)).ToList());

       var bytes = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rez));

Результат --> Cj8D
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо показать исходные данные и что получилось в C# и PHP.

Comment: ну так я показал исходные данные) массив из трех элементов

Comment: Исходные данные для base64 - последовательность байт.

Comment: Отметьте подходящий ответ, как лучший(на галку нажмите), чтобы вопрос не болтался не отвеченным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю что за Ascii таблица и прочее) Но правильный ответ был совсем близок

```
string s = System.Convert.ToBase64String(new byte [] { 10, 202, 3 });
```

Comment: Это правильный ответ для Вашего приложения, не для данного вопроса. Рекомендую всё же разобраться с тем, в чём же была проблема, а не только как её решить. Иначе в будущем наступите на те же грабли.

Answer (score 5):

Разница не в `base64_encode(php)` и `Convert.ToBase64String(c#)`, а в том, как хранятся и преобразовываются символы. Я совершенно не знаю php, поэтому даже гадать не буду, что там происходит. Зато в C# происходит следующее: Вы сохраняете символы, чьими Unicode кодами являются: `0xA`, `0xCA` и `0x3`. 
Справка по [Encoding.ASCII](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.encoding.ascii(v=vs.110).aspx) говорит нам о том, что конвертация будет произведена в 7-и битное пространство ASCII. Т.к. кодировка ASCII является 7-и битной, то всё, что выше `7F(127)` не определеяется этой кодировкой. Разумеется, `0xCA` не влазит в ASCII.

В какие байты тогда C# конвертирует `0xCA`? Не знаю, да это и не важно, важно то, что не в те, которые их конвертирует php и это очевидно из разного результата, где начало и конец одинаковы, тогда как середина разная.